# Can I check with community with my interpretation when I am not sure about my interpretation?

Tags: discussion

As a non native english speaker, I always have difficulty to interpret meaning of some words and phrases and their usages. Some times even at my best efforts I get hard time to interpret the implied meaning. Can I check with community what I had interpreted and get confirmation that my interpretation is correct or wrong? Is that acceptable as per the community rules?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully if your question is made in a genuine spirit of enquiry, it will always be answered.

But take, for example, [other meaning of the phrase “Make face”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95774/other-meaning-of-the-phrase-make-face). You hadn't realised it was just an example of the 'Indian English' tendency to drop the article (from commonplace *make **a** face*), so you ended up confusing it with the rare slang usage *make face = kiss/snog*.

I'm in complete agreement with those who voted to close that question (along with [Differences in the meaning of the words “contempt” and “Derision”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95460/differences-in-the-meaning-of-the-words-contempt-and-derision) and [Etymology for the phrase “Go to hell”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95544/etymology-for-the-phrase-go-to-hell)) because I think these are effectively General Reference.

On the other hand, I find your [Whack/Whop/Wallop](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95537/whack-someone-vs-whop-someone-vs-wallop-someone) question quite interesting. There are several subtle differences in meaning/usage there which can't easily be established using a dictionary, and I shan't be surprised if someone wants to dig deeper and give a more comprehensive answer.

My advice is to simply keep asking your questions as they arise, and don't take it too much to heart if a few get closed. As your English (and your [Google-fu](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&tbo=u&q=google+fu&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=eSHeUN64MYbO0QW-soGABw&ved=0CDEQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=f42fee5d8e10998d&bpcl=40096503&biw=1328&bih=897)) improve, that few will become fewer!